# How to implement Lucene TableSearch with jTable

Tags: java, lucene

I have been reading and searching for quite some time and can't seem to wrap my head around how to use Lucene in my Java program that contains a jTable.

What I want to be able to do is search the table when submitting a new row entry.  Do I simply create a TableModel from my jTable and pass it into the TableSearcher constructor if I include the 3.3 Lucene jar file in my path? I have included some of my code...please, I welcome any direction! Thanks.

Here is my method for populating my jTable from data stored in vectors:

...

```
public static boolean hasSearchResults = false;
public String selectedRequirementName;
public TableSearcher ts;
DefaultTableModel sc;

public TablePanel(int z, String name, String reason) { //pulls in panel number, project name, and whether the project was new or opened, from the MainGUI class
    initComponents();
    sc=(DefaultTableModel) reqTable.getModel();
    ts = new TableSearcher(sc);

    aProject = new Project(reason, name); //calls Project class to control the project

    try{

        requirementsVector = new Vector(aProject.getRequirementsList());
        requirementsList =new String[requirementsVector.size()];

        for(int i=0; i < requirementsVector.size(); i++){
            requirementsList[i] = requirementsVector.get(i).getName();
            System.out.println(requirementsList[i]);

            sc.addRow(new Object[]{
            requirementsVector.get(i).getName(),
            requirementsVector.get(i).getDefinition(),
            requirementsVector.get(i).getType(),
            requirementsVector.get(i).getPriority(),
            requirementsVector.get(i).getAssigned(),
            requirementsVector.get(i).getDue(),
            requirementsVector.get(i).getStatus()});
                //this.editingProjectName = name;

        }
    }catch(NullPointerException e1){
         System.out.println(e1);
    } ....
```

Here is my code that inserts a new row into the jTable:

```
private void ConfirmActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String ReqName = nameTextField.getText();
    String ReqDescription = descriptionTextField.getText();
    String Type = (String)jType.getSelectedItem();
    String Priority = (String)PriorityComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    String Assigned = (String)jDateAssignedMonth.getSelectedItem() + "/" + (String)jDateAssignedDay.getSelectedItem() + "/" + (String)jDateAssignedYear.getSelectedItem();
    String Due = (String)jDateDueMonth.getSelectedItem() + "/" + (String)jDateDueDay.getSelectedItem() + "/" + (String)jDateDueYear.getSelectedItem();
    String Status = (String)jStatus.getSelectedItem();

    // search string pass to TableSearcher
    ts.search(ReqDescription);


    if (editingaRow == false && !hasSearchResults){
        sc.addRow(new Object[]{
        ReqName,ReqDescription,Type,Priority,Assigned, Due, Status
        });
        requirementsVector.add(new Requirement(ReqName, ReqDescription, Type, Priority, Assigned, Due,Status));
        aProject.saveRevision(requirementsVector, name);
    }else if (editingaRow == true){
        sc.setValueAt(ReqName,selectedRow,0);
        sc.setValueAt(ReqDescription,selectedRow,1);
        sc.setValueAt(Type,selectedRow,2);
        sc.setValueAt(Priority,selectedRow,3);
        sc.setValueAt(Assigned,selectedRow,4);
        sc.setValueAt(Due,selectedRow,5);
        sc.setValueAt(Status,selectedRow,6);

        requirementsVector.setElementAt(new Requirement(ReqName, ReqDescription, Type, Priority, Assigned, Due,Status),(selectedRow));

        aProject.saveRevision(requirementsVector, name);

        editingaRow = false;

    }
    disableRequirementEditor();
    newReq.setEnabled(true);
    reqTable.clearSelection();

}
```

And here is the TableSearcher model that I am using (I added new functionality to the search method).  What is happening is when I enter a new entry, the search finds that entry as a duplicate and returns it in my jFrame I implement within search method of the TableSearcher.  This only happens with a unique entry that has no match in the indexed table. If there is a search result in the index that matches my new entry, then only the existing entry displays in my jFrame, not the new one I am attempting.

```
//  provided by Jonathan Simon <jonathan_s_simon@yahoo.com>
```

class TableSearcher extends AbstractTableModel {

```
/**
 * The inner table model we are decorating
 */
protected TableModel tableModel;

/**
 * This listener is used to register this class as a listener to
 * the decorated table model for update events
 */
private TableModelListener tableModelListener;

/**
 * these keeps reference to the decorated table model for data
 * only rows that match the search criteria are linked
 */
private ArrayList rowToModelIndex = new ArrayList();


//Lucene stuff.

/**
 * In memory lucene index
 */
private RAMDirectory directory;

/**
 * Cached lucene analyzer
 */
private Analyzer analyzer;

/**
 * Links between this table model and the decorated table model
 * are maintained through links based on row number. This is a
 * key constant to denote "row number" for indexing
 */
private static final String ROW_NUMBER = "ROW_NUMBER";

/**
 * Cache the current search String. Also used internally to
 * key whether there is an active search running or not. i.e. if
 * searchString is null, there is no active search.
 */
private String searchString = null;

/**
 * @param tableModel The table model to decorate
 */
public TableSearcher(TableModel tableModel) {
    analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();
    tableModelListener = new TableModelHandler();
    setTableModel(tableModel);
    tableModel.addTableModelListener(tableModelListener);
    clearSearchingState();
}

/**
 *
 * @return The inner table model this table model is decorating
 */
public TableModel getTableModel() {
    return tableModel;
}

/**
 * Set the table model used by this table model
 * @param tableModel The new table model to decorate
 */
public final void setTableModel(TableModel tableModel) {

    //remove listeners if there...
    if (this.tableModel != null) {
        this.tableModel.removeTableModelListener(tableModelListener);
    }

    this.tableModel = tableModel;
    if (this.tableModel != null) {
        this.tableModel.addTableModelListener(tableModelListener);
    }

    //recalculate the links between this table model and
    //the inner table model since the decorated model just changed
    reindex();

    // let all listeners know the table has changed
    fireTableStructureChanged();
}


/**
 * Reset the search results and links to the decorated (inner) table
 * model from this table model.
 */
private void reindex() {
    try {
        // recreate the RAMDirectory
        directory = new RAMDirectory();
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

        // iterate through all rows
        for (int row=0; row < tableModel.getRowCount(); row++){

            //for each row make a new document
            Document document = new Document();
            //add the row number of this row in the decorated table model
            //this will allow us to retrive the results later
            //and map this table model's row to a row in the decorated
            //table model
            document.add(new Field(ROW_NUMBER, "" + row, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            //iterate through all columns
            //index the value keyed by the column name
            //NOTE: there could be a problem with using column names with spaces
            for (int column=0; column < tableModel.getColumnCount(); column++){
                String columnName = tableModel.getColumnName(column);
                String columnValue = String.valueOf(tableModel.getValueAt(row, column)).toLowerCase();
                document.add(new Field(columnName, columnValue, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            }
            writer.addDocument(document);
        }
        writer.optimize();
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * @return The current lucene analyzer
 */
public Analyzer getAnalyzer() {
    return analyzer;
}

/**
 * @param analyzer The new analyzer to use
 */
public void setAnalyzer(Analyzer analyzer) {
    this.analyzer = analyzer;
    //reindex from the model with the new analyzer
    reindex();

    //rerun the search if there is an active search
    if (isSearching()){
        search(searchString);
    }
}

/**
 * Run a new search.
 *
 * @param searchString Any valid lucene search string
 */
public void search(String searchString){
    // to store row numbers of results rows to display later
    Vector<String> rowNums = new Vector();

    //if search string is null or empty, clear the search == search all
    if (searchString == null || searchString.equals("")){
        clearSearchingState();
        fireTableDataChanged();
        return;
    }


    try {
        //cache search String
        this.searchString = searchString;

        //make a new index searcher with the in memory (RAM) index.
        IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(directory);

        //make an array of fields - one for each column
        String[] fields = new String[tableModel.getColumnCount()];
        for (int t=0; t<tableModel.getColumnCount(); t++){
            fields[t]=tableModel.getColumnName(t);
        }

        //build a query based on the fields, searchString and cached analyzer
        //NOTE: This is an area for improvement since the MultiFieldQueryParser
        // has some weirdness.
        MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer);
        Query query = parser.parse(searchString);
        //run the search
        Hits hits = is.search(query);
       for (int t=0; t<hits.length(); t++){

            Document document = hits.doc(t);
            Fieldable field = document.getField(ROW_NUMBER);
            // adding row numbers to vector
            rowNums.add(field.stringValue());

        }

        // trying to display search results in new table
        if(!rowNums.isEmpty()){
                TablePanel.hasSearchResults = true;
                for (int v=0; v<rowNums.size(); v++){
                    System.out.println("Match in row number  " + rowNums.elementAt(v));
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Possible Duplicates");

                String colNames[] = {"Name", "Definition", "Type", "Priority", "Date Assigned", "Due Date", "Status"};

                DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(null,colNames);

                for (int r = 0; r<rowNums.size(); r++){
                    String ReqName = (String) tableModel.getValueAt(Integer.parseInt(rowNums.elementAt(r)), 0);
                    String ReqDescription = (String) tableModel.getValueAt(Integer.parseInt(rowNums.elementAt(r)), 1);
                    String Type = (String) tableModel.getValueAt(Integer.parseInt(rowNums.elementAt(r)), 2);
                    String Priority = (String) tableModel.getValueAt(Integer.parseInt(rowNums.elementAt(r)), 3);
                    String Assigned = (String) tableModel.getValueAt(Integer.parseInt(rowNums.elementAt(r)), 4);
                    String Due = (String) tableModel.getValueAt(Integer.parseInt(rowNums.elementAt(r)), 5);
                    String Status = (String) tableModel.getValueAt(Integer.parseInt(rowNums.elementAt(r)), 6);
                    dtm.addRow(new Object[]{
                         ReqName,ReqDescription,Type,Priority,Assigned, Due, Status
                           });
                }

                JTable tblResults = new JTable(dtm);
                JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(tblResults);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,300));
                panel.add(sp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                panel.add(new JLabel("Possible Duplicates",JLabel.CENTER),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,panel);

            }
        //reset this table model with the new results
        resetSearchResults(hits);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //notify all listeners that the table has been changed
    fireTableStructureChanged();
}

/**
 *
 * @param hits The new result set to set this table to.
 */
private void resetSearchResults(Hits hits) {
    try {
        //clear our index mapping this table model rows to
        //the decorated inner table model
        rowToModelIndex.clear();
        //iterate through the hits
        //get the row number stored at the index
        //that number is the row number of the decorated
        //tabble model row that we are mapping to
        for (int t=0; t<hits.length(); t++){
            Document document = hits.doc(t);
            Fieldable field = document.getField(ROW_NUMBER);
            rowToModelIndex.add(new Integer(field.stringValue()));
            System.out.println("Something  " + rowToModelIndex.add(new Integer(field.stringValue())));
            clearSearchingState();
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private int getModelRow(int row){
    return ((Integer) rowToModelIndex.get(row)).intValue();
}

/**
 * Clear the currently active search
 * Resets the complete dataset of the decorated
 * table model.
 */
private void clearSearchingState(){
    searchString = null;
    rowToModelIndex.clear();
    for (int t=0; t<tableModel.getRowCount(); t++){
        rowToModelIndex.add(new Integer(t));
    }
}

// TableModel interface methods
public int getRowCount() {
    return (tableModel == null) ? 0 : rowToModelIndex.size();
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return (tableModel == null) ? 0 : tableModel.getColumnCount();
}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return tableModel.getColumnName(column);
}

public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    return tableModel.getColumnClass(column);
}

public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return tableModel.isCellEditable(getModelRow(row), column);
}

public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    return tableModel.getValueAt(getModelRow(row), column);
}

public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
    tableModel.setValueAt(aValue, getModelRow(row), column);
}

private boolean isSearching() {
    return searchString != null;
}

private class TableModelHandler implements TableModelListener {
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        // If we're not searching, just pass the event along.
        if (!isSearching()) {
            clearSearchingState();
            reindex();
            fireTableChanged(e);
            return;
        }

        // Something has happened to the data that may have invalidated the search.
        reindex();
        search(searchString);
        fireTableDataChanged();
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code doesn't index the table data with Lucene. One easy way to do this is to make your own table model that indexes internally, with an exposed search function that you can connect to limit the data displayed. This is what I wrote about in Swing Hacks a few years back.

Without the indexing, Lucene won't just automatically 'work' because it's in your classpath.

Jonathan

Comment: So I might do something like add another class called TableSearcher that is much like this one http://demo.spars.info/j/frameset.cgi?compo_id=61780&mode=frameset&ref=3&method=334&CASE=0&MORPHO=1&location=1111111111111111111&LANG=1 and then pass my current table model in here after hitting the "save" button on my application.  Then I could display this data in a pop up jpanel/jtable?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [very simple example](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/TheBasics)

in your case, you would do something like this to create the document, that would get saved in the index.

this code is not complete or necessarily error free,; but is more of a starting point to get you going

```
  Document doc = new Document(); 
  doc.add(new Field("ReqName", ReqName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));   
  doc.add(new Field("ReqDescription", ReqDescription, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED)); 
  doc.add(new Field("Type", Type, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));   
  doc.add(new Field("Priority", Priority, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));   
  doc.add(new Field("Assigned", Assigned, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));   
  doc.add(new Field("Due", Due, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));   
  doc.add(new Field("Status", Status, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));   
  writer.addDocument(doc); 
  writer.close();
```